# A question of line bundle for finite etale covering

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi, everyone, I want to ask a question about line bundle.

Let $X$ be a smooth curve over a algebraically closed field $k$, and $f:Y \longrightarrow X$ a Galois finite etale covering with Galois group $G$ and degree $n$. Suppose that $L$ is a line bundle on $X$.

Dose there exist a line bundle $M$ on $Y$ such that $M^{\otimes n}=f^{*}L$?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $C/k$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $U/C$ be a line bundle. If $n|{\rm deg}(U)$ then there exists a line bundle $R$ such that $R^{\otimes n}=U$. This follows from the fact that multiplication by $n$ is an isogeny on the ${\rm Pic}_0(C)$ and thus the tensoring by $n$ morphism ${\rm Pic}_{{\rm deg}(U)/n}\to {\rm Pic}_{{\rm deg}(U)}$ is surjective. 
This applies to your set-up, with $Y=C$ and $U=f^*L$. 

See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44692/what-is-a-square-root-of-a-line-bundle

Comment: Why did you make this a comment and not an answer?